# Getting error while logging in due to unknown bcrypt issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt, mern

I'm working on the backend with `nodejs and mongodb` . After coding `authentication` part i'm having unknown issue and i think it's from `bcrypt` :(

please have a look at my code.

**USER MODEL CODE -**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const validator = require("validator");
require("dotenv").config();

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      lowercase: true,
      validate(value) {
        if (!validator.isEmail) {
          throw new Error("Invalid Email");
        }
      },
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["user", "admin"],
      default: "user",
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 21,
    },
    phone: {
      required: true,
      type: Number,
      maxlength: 12,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (this.isModified("password")) {
    // hash the password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    this.password = hash;
  }
  next();
});

userSchema.methods.generateToken = function () {
  const userObj = { id: this._id.toHexString(), email: this.email };
  const token = jwt.sign(userObj, process.env.DB_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "3d",
  });
  return token;
};

userSchema.statics.emailTaken = async function (email) {
  const user = await this.findOne({ email });
  return !!user;
};

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = {
  User,
};
```

**USER API CODE** (Please avoid those bunch of console log statements as i had added them for debugging purpose) -

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
require("dotenv").config();
const { User } = require("../../models/userModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

// const comparePassword = async (userPassword) => {
//   console.log("Comparing password with bcrypt");
//   const match = await bcrypt.compare(userPassword, this.password);
//   console.log(match);
//   return match;
// };

router.route("/signup").post(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, name, phone } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);

  try {
    // Check if user email exists
    if (await User.emailTaken(email)) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email already exists" });
    }

    // create user instance and hash password
    const user = new User({
      email: email,
      password: password,
      name: name,
      phone: phone,
    });

    // generate jwt token
    console.log("user is saving");
    const token = user.generateToken();
    const userDoc = await user.save();

    // send email

    // save....send token with cookie
    res.cookie("access-token", token).status(200).send(returnUserDoc(userDoc));
  } catch (error) {
    res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: "Error while creating user", error: error });
  }
});

router.route("/login").post(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Find user
    console.log("Finding User........");
    let user = await User.find({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid Credentials" });
    }

    // Compare Password
    console.log("Comparing password with bcrypt");
    const match = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    console.log("password compared");
    console.log(match);
    if (match == false) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid Credentials" });
    }

    console.log("Password Matched");

    // Generate Token
    console.log("Generating Token........");
    const token = user.generateToken();

    // Response
    console.log("Sending Response........");
    res.cookie("access-token", token).status(200).send(returnUserDoc(user));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error");
    res.status(400).json({ message: "Error while loggin in", error: error });
  }
});

// functions
const returnUserDoc = (userDoc) => {
  return {
    _id: userDoc._id,
    name: userDoc.name,
    email: userDoc.email,
    phone: userDoc.phone,
  };
};

module.exports = router;
```

CONSOLE LOGS -

```
listening on port 3001
Database Connected
Finding User........
Comparing password with bcrypt
Error
```

I have found that code is executing successfully just before `const match = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);` this line

On `console.log(error.message);` i'm getting this -

```
 Error: data and hash arguments required
    at Object.compare (D:\CovidHelpers\CovidHelpers\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:208:17)
    at D:\CovidHelpers\CovidHelpers\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:29:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.module.exports.promise (D:\CovidHelpers\CovidHelpers\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:20:12)
    at Object.compare (D:\CovidHelpers\CovidHelpers\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:204:25)
    at D:\CovidHelpers\CovidHelpers\server\routes\api\users.js:60:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
data and hash arguments required
```

Please help me fix this :)
**Thank You**

Comment: you should print the error to know what it is. in your catch, do `console.log(error.message)`. We cannot help you without knowing what the error says

Comment: sure, refresh this page please :)

Comment: Please use findOne method to find the users against an email,most probably the user password or req.body.password is missing, can you console log user for me or user.password?

Comment: console.log `req.body.password` and `user.password` and make sure they are not equal to undefined or null

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh !!!!!! sorry for the silly mistake :( yes, I should write findOne so that it'll return an object. Thank you guys !